# Is it possible to split a yaml file?

Tags: yaml, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

The file I use to run in the pipeline is getting too big, is there any way to separate the steps into different files and just call them in the main file?

Comment: No. https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/ is your only chance to reduce the size of your pipelines file.

Comment: "Getting too big". Too big for what? You can (and probably should) just generate the yaml the bitbucket wants from something more sensible before pushing your repository.

Comment: You might want to rally in this issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21790 that is still gathering interest.